# How to play Serious Sam 3: BFE in fullscreen mode

Tags: windows-7

When I start the game, [Serious Sam 3: BFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serious_Sam_3:_BFE), it is in a windowed mode. How can I play this game in fullscreen, without the title bar, etc?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the time to improve your question. See our [How to Ask](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask) and the [Rubber Duck Problem Solving](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch between fullscreen and windowed mode by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.